# Generating a unique ID for an application instance

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, uuid

I'm looking to generate a unique identifier (String) for the application instance.

I need this because I'm storing user profiles in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) in this format:

```
/phones/{phoneId}/users/{user}/
```

..where there are multiple user profiles on 1 device (no authentication). `phoneId` is meant to be the unique string identifier for the application instance.

However, when I perform:

```
var uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
Log.d("UniqueID", uniqueID )
```

`uniqueId` returns a random string every time. [The documentation states that "GUIDs can also be used to uniquely identify an app instance"](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#working_with_instance_ids_&_guids)- but like I said I'm not getting the same string every time `uniqueId` prints.

Any reason why this is or if there's a better alternative to have an immutable string to uniquely identify the app instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` it generates a unique ID. That is by definition. If you want a single unique ID, you should only call `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` once and store the value in something like `SharedPreferences` between app starts.

Note that this is pretty similar to the purpose of [Firebase Instance IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId), so you might also consider using that to identify the device.

Comment: Calling it once and storing in SharedPreferences seems like a very simple and effective way to go about it - however, how do I call `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`  and store in `SharedPreferences` when the application is installed? As I only want it to be called once.

Comment: @Zorgan when the app starts you check whether you find the uuid in the sharedprefs. if you don't, you generate one and save it to the sharedprefs.